# Implement delegate in didSelectItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, delegates

I am using delegate to make a connection between a `UICollectionViewCell` and  a `UICollectionViewController`. In this connection I want to say, if user clicks on a `UIView` its super class is changed, I already did it by using gesture.
The only problem is, I think I have to implement this delegation into the `didSelectItemAt` protocol of `UIcollectionView`', which I am not sure to how to do it.

For example, first I did it in the `cellForItemAt`, which was a mistake, buy I could implement easily.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath) as? ListCell
    cell?.selectionDelegate = self // implement the delegate
}
```

but I don't know how to do the same thing in `didSelectItemAt`, because I think I should do it here, not in `cellForItemAt`

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you had your original selection delegate:

```swift
protocol SelectionDelegate {
    func didSelect(_ cell: ListCell)
}
```

Then you can easily implement collectionView's didSelect by just calling your selection delegate:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ListCell else { return }
    didSelect(cell)
}
```

Comment: Implementation may change depends on how your `SelectionDelegate` originally declared